# Capistrano foreman cannot export upstart scripts because it's trying to run commands as root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3, foreman

I'm using capistrano3-foreman gem to deploy my app into production which is in a centOS server but capistrano is trying to run foreman export command from root. Since I have installed rvm and other stuff from a user which has no password privilege in sudoers file, foreman export cannot be completed.

I'm getting the following error.

```
sh: /root/.rvm/bin/rvm: No such file or directory
```

How can I prevent capistrano-foreman from trying to run the command as root and make it set to my user home path.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since RHEL & CentOS 7 migrated to systemd, first mistake was trying to export foreman to upstart.

But When I exported foreman to systemd, systemd did not recognised foreman export scripts as a service so it didn't work either.

After many hours of work & research I decided to take my chance with supervisord on CentOS 7 and now It works like a charm.

http://supervisord.org/installing.html

And please note that Debian & Ubuntu are also getting rid of upstart...